# Not Fetch All column in the data in database and only one can retrieve

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi everyone I have a problem with my query..
When I try To a data one by one same result and the result that retrieve is on the last [id](http://prntscr.com/2rsjsi) of the [database](http://prntscr.com/2rsjyb)

This is my codes..

```
$code = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,code FROM table_inventory");

$code->execute();
$code->bind_result($id,$ccode);

$res = $code->get_result();

   while ($row = $res->fetch_array()){

        $id = $row['id'];
        $co = $row['code'];
   }

<form role="form">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
<input type="test" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="code">Item Code</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" placeholder="code" value="<?php echo $co; ?>">
</div>
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, that's what it should do because you are storing multiple `id` and `code` into **variables** and **not arrays**. You need to store in `id[]` and `code[]` and then use `foreach` to loop through all the values.

Comment: How to do this can you give me an example
because i'm new in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but something like this:

```
while ($row = $res->fetch_array()){

        $id[] = $row['id'];
        $co[] = $row['code'];
   }

<form role="form">

<?php
    foreach($id as $ind=>$val){ ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id[$ind]; ?>">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
<input type="test" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="code">Item Code</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" placeholder="code" value="<?php echo $co[$ind]; ?>">
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I'm guessing this isn't your full code by the way, because your PHP and HTML are mixed in.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply
but i try to foreach and this is the [result](http://prntscr.com/2rtl3w) 

and the my codes is this

`$code = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT code FROM table_inventory");

$code->execute();
$code->bind_result($ccode);

$code->store_result();


while ($code->fetch()){

    $codes[] = $ccode;

}
 <div class="form-group">
                                                      <label for="itemcode">Itemcode</label>
<?php foreach($codes as $c): ?>
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$c?>" id="">
<?php endforeach; ?>
`

Comment: Can I know your desired output?